# where shall I write backend call inside AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to do a backend call inside directive with one of attribute. If I write this inside link function it calls multiple time to backend. Where shall I put my backend call so that it will call single time only and performance will be good also. I am using directive inside ng-repeat. so it's getting called multiple times.

Comment: are you using your directive inside an ng-repeat?

Comment: you mean directive declare multiple time but communication with server only one time?

Comment: Need a lot more details to get a proper answer

Comment: yeah i am using directive inside ng-repeat and edited the question also.

Comment: Yeah @Sandeep, that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service, and inject it in your directive.
See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

A service is a singleton, and this is exactly what you need to have backend communication only one time.